# nginx access from redirection from specific ip

Tags: redirect, nginx

I have 2 servers, the frontend (tornado) and the static file server (nginx). Does someone here know how to access the files from the static file server only if the request is redirected from the frontend. If the request is made directly to the static file server, the request will be denied.

Comment: How does the frontend request the static file?

Comment: through redirection having http protocol

Comment: Paste an example in your question?

Comment: Ex. I have server_1.com and server_2.com running on different IPs. If a user access http://server_2.com/file.zip he will be denied but if he access http:/server_1.com/file=101 he will be redirected and download http://server_2.com/file.zip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the variable: `$http_referer`:

```
if ($http_referer !~ "^http://server_1.com.*$"){
    return 403;
}
```

Comment: sure. Have you tested it? Any question please feel free to comment here.